# How do you request additional quota for Google Cloud DLP API?

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

I'd like to request additional quota for use with the Google Cloud DLP API.  What is the best way to request a quota increase?

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for requesting quota are now at https://cloud.google.com/dlp/limits#quota_increases